# Hibernate Entity with @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable. Hibernate add attribute name to SQL statement when retrieve the collection

Tags: java, hibernate, documentum

In my case I have two Tables:
parent 'VDI_DICT_EMPOYEES_SV' and chield 'VDI_DICT_EMPOYEES_RV' joined by column with the same name 'R_OBJECT_ID'. (See ER Diagram)

[image]

The structure of the 'parent' Entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VDI_DICT_EMPLOYEE_SV")
public class DmDictEmployee {
  @Column (name="R_OBJECT_ID") private String objectId;

... other columns are skipped...

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="VDI_EMPLOYEE_RV, joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CROC_SECRETARY_ID",referencedColumnName="R_OBJECT_ID"))
 private List<String> crocSecretaryIds; // the element collection

... getters and setters are skipped too...

}
```

To fetch the master and slave data I use the native @Query

```
"SELECT parent.*, chield.CROC_SECRETARY_ID from VDI_DICT_EMPLOYEE_SV parent left outer join VDI_DICT_EMPLOYEE_RV chield on parent.R_OBJECT_ID=chield.R_OBJECT_ID"
```

(This selects employee entry with list of secretary in one select)

And it works fine as I see from the log. The query returns data just fine. But when I try to retrieve the list of crocSecretaryIds I see the HIBERNATE prepares the SQL which includes the collection name:
"SELECT CROC_SECRETARY_ID, **crocSecretaryIds** FROM VDI_DICT_EMPLOYEES_RV WHERE R_OBJECT_ID=..." (see next screenshot)

[image]

which is quite odd. I expected to see the SQL query without **crocSecretaryIds** so, I assume something wrong with my declaration of the @ElementCollection column.
Could you please to advise any ideas what is missed and why the HIBERNATE prepares query with **crocSecretaryIds**?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I realized that I incorrectly referenced the "child" table.
Instead of

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="VDI_EMPLOYEE_RV, joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CROC_SECRETARY_ID",referencedColumnName="R_OBJECT_ID"))
 private List<String> crocSecretaryIds; // the element collection
```

I need to do:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="VDI_EMPLOYEE_RV, joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="R_OBJECT_ID",referencedColumnName="R_OBJECT_ID"))
@Column(name="CROC_SECRETARY_ID") // the column name in child table
private List<String> crocSecretaryIds;
```

So, it works now.